# How to write Integration Tests to test REST endpoints in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration-testing

I just started in a new project that uses Java EE instead of Spring Boot for their MVC. Since I am very used to Spring and have no experience in Java EE I wonder how I can test the REST endpoints.
I know `MockMvc` or `WebTestClient` from Spring Boot. What is the equivalent to write an Integration-Test/API-Test in Java EE? I was not able to find anything useful using Google so far. Maybe I am missing some special keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, but here are some options:

- Arquillian
- RestAssured
- WireMock
- MicroShed

Comment: WireMock sounds great